# Minimize $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, convex-optimization

Given sequence:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}(2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n)=1,\forall n\geq 1\\
x_1=x\in\mathbb R,m\in\mathbb N,m\geq 2
\end{cases}
$$
Minimize $$A=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2$$
**Edit**

I've proved that $\frac{dA}{dx}|_{x=-1}=0$ (see my answer). The problem now is to show that $A_{\min}=A|_{x=-1}$ is the global minimum.

**The part below belongs to the original post**

$A$ is actually the area bounded by the zig-zag loop between $y=\frac{1}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x}$ and $y=x$. I tried it on a computer and observed that $A$ minimizes at $x=-1,\forall m$, and other $m-1$ values of $x$, resulting in the same minimal value of $A$ (the only minimum of $A$). I did try to prove the necessary condition $\frac{dA}{dx} |_{x=-1}=0$, after some algebra, the equivalent equation is:$$\sum_{k=1}^m \left(x_k-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m}\right)x_{k+1}^2+x_{k+1}^3\right)\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^2|_{x=-1}=0$$
I recognized a sort of symmetry inside the sum (sum of two terms (of the sum above) with indices adding up to $m$ is $0$ and the last term is $0$ as well) but I couldn't figure out how to deal with the product in the sum. How do I proceed from here?
Also, with the necessary condition proved, how can I show that there is exactly one minimal value of $A$ for every $m$?

[image]
[Feel free to check out [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hhrhcesjei)]

Comment: Why is such a problem important?

Comment: Not sure. I just want to learn about the "behaviour" of area $A$ (which is only well-defined for cyclic sequences), and the limit of this minimal area is actually $\pi^2$, I find it interesting

Comment: Could you add the calculation that yields $A$?

Comment: You mean this formula $A=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2$ ?

Comment: It is possible to find an explicit formula for $x_n$. As it is a rational difference. The formula is terrible, so I don't think it is usefull, but is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%281%29%3Dx%3B+a%28n%2B1%29%3D1%2F%28a%28n%29%2Bk%29) one ($k=\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})$)

Comment: @Amir The line $y=x$ seperates two continuous branchs of $y=\frac{1}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x}$ and the area $A$ can be broken into isosceles right triangles with side length $|x_{k+1}-x_k|$, as the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is cyclic, there are exactly $m$ triangles. You can check out the graph generator I added above.

Answer (score 4):

Not yet the solution, but I found

1. The closed form expression of $(x_k)_k$
2. The minimum and the $m$ values of $x$ such that $A$ reaches its minimum
3. It is **not necessary** to find the miminum for $\color{red}{x \in \mathbb{R}} $. It suffices to find the global minimum $A_{\min}$ for $\color{red}{x\in (-\infty,0)}$.

---

### 1

For the sake of simplicity, let us denote $\alpha = \pi/m$ and $t_1,t_2$ be the two solutions of
$$t= \frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -t } $$
then
$$t_{1,2} = e^{\pm \mathbf{i} \frac{\pi}{m}} = e^{\pm \mathbf{i}  \alpha} = \cos(\alpha) \pm\mathbf{i}\sin(\alpha)$$
We have:
$$\begin{align}
x_{k+1} -t_1&= \frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -x_k }-\frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -t_1 }\\
& = \frac{x_k-t_1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -x_k }\cdot\frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -t_1 }\\
x_{k+1} -t_1& = \frac{x_k-t_1}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -x_k }\cdot t_1 \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Same for $t_2$, we have:
$$x_{k+1} -t_2= \frac{x_k-t_2}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m} \right) -x_k }\cdot t_2\tag{2}$$

$(1)/(2)$ we deduce:
$$\frac{x_{k+1} -t_1}{x_{k+1} -t_2} = \frac{x_{k} -t_1}{x_{k} -t_2}\cdot \frac{t_1}{t_2}\tag{3}$$
From $(3)$, we deduce the closed form expression of $x_k$ for $k \in \{1,...,m \}$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x_{k} -t_1}{x_{k} -t_2} = \frac{x -t_1}{x -t_2} \left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)^{k-1}  &\implies x_k= \frac{x(t_2^{k-2}-t_1^{k-2})-(t_2^{k-1}-t_1^{k-1})}{x(t_2^{k-1}-t_1^{k-1})-(t_2^{k}-t_1^{k})}\\
&\implies \color{red}{x_k= \frac{x\sin((k-2)\alpha) - \sin((k-1)\alpha)}{x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha)}}  \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

---

Thanks to Mathematica, from $(4)$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
 (x_{k+1}-x_k)^2  &= \left(\frac{x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha)}{x\sin(k\alpha) - \sin(({k+1})\alpha)} - \frac{x\sin((k-2)\alpha) - \sin((k-1)\alpha)}{x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha)}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{(1-2\cos(\alpha)x+x^2)^2 \cdot \sin^4 (\alpha)}{(x\sin(k\alpha) - \sin(({k+1})\alpha))^2(x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha))^2}
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\color{red}{A = \frac{\sin^4 (\alpha) }{2}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(1-2\cos(\alpha)x+x^2)^2}{(x\sin(k\alpha) - \sin(({k+1})\alpha))^2(x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha))^2}}$$

---

### 2

$A$ reaches its minimum

$$\color{red}{A_{\min} =2\sin^4(\alpha)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(2k\alpha))^2}}$$

if and only if $x$ is equal to one of these $m$ values

$$\color{red}{x = \frac{\sin\left(\left(h-\frac{1}{2}\right)\alpha\right)}{\sin\left(\left(h+\frac{1}{2}\right)\alpha\right)}   \hspace{1cm }\text{for }h=1,...,m}$$

---

### 3

From $(4)$, we notice that

- the product of $(x_k)_k$ is negative:
  $$\prod_{k=1}^m x_k = \prod_{k=1}^m\frac{x\sin((k-2)\alpha) - \sin((k-1)\alpha)}{x\sin((k-1)\alpha) - \sin(k\alpha)} = -1$$
  So, there exists *at least* a $h \in \{ 1,2,...,m\}$ such that $x_h<0$ (just for information, *graphically*, we can see that there exist a unique $x_h$ such that $x_h<0$, all others are positive).
- the sequence is cyclic with period $m$ (i.e $x_{m+1} = x_1$) and the sum $A$ is also cyclic. So, if there exists a $x^*$ such that $A(x^*) = A_{ \min}$, the sequence will be
  $$x_1 = x^{*} \to x_2(x^*) \to ... \to x_m(x^*)$$
  then there exists a $h \in \{ 1,2,...,m\}$ such that $x_h(x^*)<0$ and we can consider $x_h(x^*)$ as the first element $x_1 = x:= x_h(x^*)<0$.

By consequence, we can restrict the domain to $x \in (-\infty,0)$ for finding the mimimum of $A$.

Besides, if there exists a $x^*<0$ such that $A(x^*) = A_{ \min}$, the other $m-1$ values $x_k(x^*)$ ($k=2,..,m$) also satisfy
$$A(x_k(x^*)) = A_{ \min} \hspace{1cm} \text{for }k=2,...,m$$

**Objective**: What we need to prove
$$\color{red}{\min_{x \in (-\infty,0)}A(x) = A(-1)}$$

*Remark*: in the domain $x\in (-\infty,0)$, *graphically*, $A(x)$ is a convex function and has a unique mimimum at $x = -1$.

[image]

Comment: 1) Is the sequence the same as one obtained in Marko's comment? 2) Is $-1$ (claimed in the OP) one of the $m$ values you found?

Comment: @Amir For $h = 1$, you obtain the value $-1$. And I believe the two sequences are the same (mine is much simpler).

Comment: So which part is missing in your current answer (as you stated: Not yet the solution)?

Comment: @Amir I haven't proven the $A_{\min}$ is a minimum yet. Currently, I'm just able to give the minimum value.

Comment: A typo. For $h=m$ (not $h=1$), we have the value $x=-1$.

Comment: (+1) very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to answer my own question but **it is not yet a complete answer**. I will only prove $\frac{dA}{dx}|_{x=-1}=0$.

Continuing from [NN2](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/195378/nn2)'s work:
$$A=2\sin(\alpha)^4\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(2k\alpha)+(x+1)G_k(x))^2};\alpha=\frac{\pi}{m}$$
Where $$G_k(x)=\frac{(\cos(2k\alpha)-\cos((2k-1)\alpha))(x+1)+2\sin(\alpha)\sin(2k\alpha)}{x^2-2\cos(\alpha)x+1}$$
[This can be verified easily by algebra] $$\frac{dA}{dx}|_{x=-1}=-4\sin(\alpha)^4\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{G_k(x)+(x+1)G'_k(x)}{(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(2k\alpha)+(x+1)G_k(x))^3}|_{x=-1}$$ $$=-4\sin(\alpha)^4\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{G_k(-1)}{(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(2k\alpha))^3}=\frac{-4\sin(\alpha)^5}{1+\cos(\alpha)}\sum_{k=1}^mB(k)$$
Where $$B(k)=\frac{\sin(2k\alpha)}{(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(2k\alpha))^3}$$
It is straightforward that:$$B(k)+B(m-k)=0,\forall k$$
Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^mB(k)=0\Rightarrow \frac{dA}{dx}|_{x=-1}=0$$

Comment: $\frac{dA}{dx}|_{x=-1}=0$ with $\frac{d^2A}{dx^2}|_{x=-1}>0$ only means that  $x=-1$ is a **local minimum**.  To complete the proof, you may show the convexity of $A$ (but  $A$ may be a non-convex function, please check it for some $m$), or alternatively, show that $\frac{dA}{dx}\ge 0$ for $x>-1$ and $\frac{dA}{dx}\le 0$ for $x<-1$ .

Comment: It turns out that $\frac{d^2A}{dx^2}|_{x=-1}>0$ is not so obvious, my bad. I edited my answer

Comment: Using your answer, I just completed the proof in my in my answer. Also, I have shown how the problem can be efficiently solved for similar functions using convex optimization.

Answer (score 0):

First note that the problem in the OP:

minimization of $$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2$$

subject to:

$$
x_{n+1}(2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n)=1, \quad n\geq 1\\
x_1=x\in\mathbb R,m\in\mathbb N,m\geq 2
$$

can be written as the following  **convex optimization** model (for $m\in\mathbb N,m\geq 2$):

$$ \color{blue}{\text{P:} \, \min \quad \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2}$$

subject to:

$$
\color{blue}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n+x_{n+1} \ge \sqrt{4+\left (2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n-x_{n+1}\right )^2},\quad n\geq 1\\
x_1=x\in\mathbb R }.
$$

This optimization model is classified as a second-order cone programming model. It worth noting that for any $\epsilon >0$, an $\epsilon$-optimal solution of such an optimization model can be found in polynomial time, and many powerful solvers have been developed for solving this class of optimization models, which includes convex quadratic programming models. **Hence, the above model can be used to solve the problem in the OP for any other similar function other than** $$y=\frac{1}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x}.$$

Let $\color{blue}{A(a)}$ denote the optimal value of the model $\text{P}$ by **fixing** $\color{blue}{x}$ to $a$, i.e., the optimal value of the following model, called $\text{P}(a)$:

$$ \color{blue}{\text{P}(\color{blue}{a }): \, \min \quad \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{k+1}-x_{k})^2}$$

subject to:

$$
2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n+x_{n+1} \ge \sqrt{4+\left (2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n-x_{n+1}\right )^2},\quad n\geq 1\\
x_1=x, \color{blue}{x=a }.
$$

Let $(x(a)^*_1, \cdots, x(a)^*_{m+1})$ denote an optimal solution of $\text{P}(a)$. Now I show for any $a$ and $b$ and any $\alpha \in [0,1]$,

$$A(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b) \le \alpha A( a)+ (1-\alpha)A(b). $$

As the feasible space of the original model $\text{P}$ is a convex set, then $$(y^*_1, \cdots, y^*_{m+1})=\alpha (x^*(a)_1, \cdots, x^*(a)_{m+1})+(1-\alpha) (x^*(b)_1, \cdots, x^*(b)_{m+1})$$ is a feasible solution for model $\text{P}(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b)$. Moreover, from the convexity of  the objective function, we have

$$A(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m \left (x^*(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b)_{k+1}-x^*(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b)_{k} \right)^2 \le \\  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^m (y_{k+1}-y_{k})^2   \le \\ \alpha\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x^*(a)_{k+1}-x^*(a)_{k})^2+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^m (x^*(b)_{k+1}-x^*(b)_{k})^2\alpha \\= A( a)+ (1-\alpha)A(b) $$

Therefore, $A(x)$ **is a convex function**.

Also, from @QuýNhânĐặngHoàng's answer, in which @NN2's answer was used, we know that $$\frac{dA(x)}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=-1}=0.$$ Thus, $x=-1$ is the optimal solution, and the proof of the claim in the OP is completed.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by " **fixing** $\color{blue}x$". I think your approach of proving $A(x)$ (or $A^*(x)$) a convex function need to have more explication.

Comment: @NN2 you may check the updated answer.

Comment: You supposed there are $2$ solutions (that minimize $A$) $a$ and $b$. How do you know the set of "solutions" is not $\emptyset$. And it's incorrect to say that $\alpha a+ (1-\alpha)b$ is also a solution.

Comment: @NN2 I showed that $A(x)$ is a convex function. To prove this you need to show that for any $a$ and $b$ and any $\alpha \in [0,1]$, the following holds 

$$A(\alpha a+(1-\alpha) b) \le \alpha A( a)+ (1-\alpha)A(b).$$  As for each $a$ there is a sequence for which all the constraints are satisfied in equality (they are all active, $x_{n+1}(2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n)=1, \quad n\geq 1$), the model $P(a)$ has a feasible solution; other feasible solutions of $P(a)$ are those on which some constraints in $P(a)$ are not active, that is, $x_{n+1}(2\cos(\frac{\pi}{m})-x_n)>1 $ for some $n$.

Comment: Too busy for the work, I come back to this interesting problem. I see now you want to prove the convexity of $A(x)$ by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition). However, in the answer, I don't see the proof (in the answer, you just mentionned the definition of the convexity function but the proof  seemingly too short to be understood)